# How to join multiple tables in source part of db2 merge query

Tags: sql, db2

Please refer to sample db tables given below. Now in EmpDept table some records have wrong lname for employees. It has to be updated by taking the corresponding lname from Employee table. This update in EmpDept table should be done only for 'active' employees. I'm trying to use db2 merge (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0010873.html) statement. Please let me know how to accomplish this.

```
    Employee            
empID   fname   lname   status
1   abc xyz active
2   def yzx active
3   ghi zyx inactive
4   jkl zxy inactive
5   mno yxz active

    Dept            
deptID  name        
1   pqrs        
2   lmno        
3   stuv        

    EmpDept         
EmpDeptID   empID   deptID  lname
1           1   1   xyz
2           2   1   yzx
3           2   2   yzx
4           3   2   fff
5           5   3   aaa
```

Answer (score -1):

For this particular problem you should use `UPDATE` Statement, instead of `MERGE`

```
UPDATE EmpDep em
SET em.lname = (select e.lname 
from employee e 
where e.empid = em.empid 
and e.status = 'ACTIVE')
```

Here is documentation on `UPDATE` http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0010873.html

Comment: gonna have to downvote this. The user is asking for a MERGE statement it is very clear. This should have been a comment